# Get only one contact from contact list in android app

Tags: android

After picking one contact from my contact list, it doesnt get only one contact, but all of them instead.

Here's what i'm doing to get the phone number:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    Cursor phone = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
                    while(phone.moveToNext()){
                        String number = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        int type = phone.getInt(phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        this.numeros.add(number);
                    }                   
                }
                break;
            }
            this.mostarToast(this.numeros.size() + " contatos adicionados.");
        } else {
            // gracefully handle failure
            Log.w("Erro", "Erro ao adicionar contato!");
        }
    }
```

The "mostrarToast" method is just for showing how many contacts i have picked. But instead of one, it shows like 101 contacts. How can i pick exactly one?

Answer (score 0):

I think that youre picking all numbers instead of a single one:

```
Cursor phone = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+" = ?" ,new String[]{id},null);
```

This will fetch all numbers from that only contact id, try it

Comment: Some contacts can come without phone numbers, you can try with another one.